# Using different actions from a single BeginForm

Tags: c#, submit, asp.net-mvc-5, html.beginform

I got a form where I got details of a product displayed.On submit of this form it goes to the "Dropshipment" action as my beginformm is as

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DropShipment", "LoadProduct", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
```

However, during an edit process,I used the same UI to allow the edit, now when I am submitting, obviously it will go to the "Dropshipment" action again. However I want it to submit to an "Edit" action.

How can I achieve this ?

Below is how I put my partial
[image]

Comment: How do you define it is Edit prosess or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the desired action string ("DropShipment" or "Edit") in a new property in the model that is given to your _Partial. This action string can be set in your Controller which I am assuming is "LoadProduct". Then just plug it into the Html.BeginForm parameters.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(Model.MyDesiredAction, "LoadProduct", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help guys.

I solved the issue by putting the Beginform outside my Partial.
I am posting my solution for future visitors.

[image]

Cheers all.